# Test.QuickCheck: speed up testing multiple properties for the same type

Tags: testing, haskell, quickcheck, htf

I am testing a random generator generating instances of my own type. For that I have a custom instance of `Arbitrary`:

```
complexGenerator :: (RandomGen g) => g -> (MyType, g)

instance Arbitrary MyType where
    arbitrary = liftM (fst . complexGenerator . mkStdGen) arbitrary
```

This works well with `Test.QuickCheck` (actually, `Test.Framework`) for testing that the generated values hold certain properties. However, there are quite a few properties I want to check, and the more I add, the more time it takes to verify them all.

Is there a way to use the same generated values for testing every property, instead of generating them anew each time? I obviously still want to see, on failures, *which* property did not hold, so making one giant property with `and` is not optimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I obviously still want to see, on failures, which property did not hold, so making one giant property with `and` is not optimal.

You could label each property using [`printTestCase`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/QuickCheck/2.6/doc/html/Test-QuickCheck.html#v%3aprintTestCase) before making a giant property with [`conjoin`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/QuickCheck/2.6/doc/html/Test-QuickCheck.html#v%3aconjoin).

e.g. you were thinking this would be a bad idea:

```
prop_giant :: MyType -> Bool
prop_giant x = and [prop_one x, prop_two x, prop_three x]
```

this would be as efficient yet give you better output:

```
prop_giant :: MyType -> Property
prop_giant x = conjoin [printTestCase "one" $ prop_one x,
                        printTestCase "two" $ prop_two x,
                        printTestCase "three" $ prop_three x]
```

(Having said that, I've never used this method myself and am only assuming it will work; `conjoin` is probably marked as experimental in the documentation for a reason.)

Answer (score 1):

In combination with the voted answer, what I've found helpful is using a Reader transformer with the Writer monad:

```
type Predicate r = ReaderT r (Writer String) Bool
```

The Reader "shared environment" is the tested input in this case. Then you can compose properties like this:

```
inv_even :: Predicate Int
inv_even = do
  lift . tell $ "this is the even invariant"
  (==) 0 . flip mod 2 <$> ask 

toLabeledProp :: r -> Predicate r -> Property
toLabeledProp cause r =
  let (effect, msg) = runWriter . (runReaderT r) $ cause in
    printTestCase ("inv: " ++ msg) . property $ effect
```

and combining:

```
fromPredicates :: [Predicate r] -> r -> Property
fromPredicates predicates cause =
  conjoin . map (toLabeledProp cause) $ predicates
```

I suspect there is another approach involving something similar to Either or a WriterT here- which would concisely compose predicates on different types into one result. But at the least, this allows for documenting properties which impose different post-conditions dependent on the the value of the input.

Edit: This idea spawned a library: 
http://github.com/jfeltz/quickcheck-property-comb